# Flutter -> Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar How to get out

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am looking for a way to get out of the persistent bottom Navigation bar. once we enter in it I've tried to almost every rout to get out of it. but it doesn't work in any of them. just a simple back button and the whole thing vanishes leaving the point where i called the bottom Navigation bar.
Do help me out on this one.

Regards.

Comment: Can you please share some context? What `persistent bottom navigation bar` are you talking about? Did you implement it on your own or used a package?

Comment: Once i enter in the presistent Nav bar from login, then tried almost every navigation rout to go back in the login via click but am unable. it so happens that when i press back button from device then it closes the whole nav bar and return to login screen where the nav bar called..

What i am looking for is a solution to close/dispose the whole nav bar and move back to the login where it was call but on click where i can add some logic for logout like barrier token, google map redirection or other stuff..

Comment: Okay I get that. :) And which persistent bottom navigation bar are you using? Something like this: https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf or did you use a package? In order to get help you need to share some context / code.

Comment: yes that one, do you any solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return LoginScreen();
            },
          ),
          (_) => false,
        ));
```

I found this solution from the [issue here](https://github.com/BilalShahid13/PersistentBottomNavBar/issues/70).

Comment: Adding thhe rootNavigator:true did it for me

Answer (score 2):

You can get the intendent result by storing the root page `buildContext`. This allows you to later on navigate based on that `context`.

Storing the `context` can be done the following way:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ContextKeeper {
  static BuildContext buildContext;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    buildContext = context;
  }
}
```

Now call the `init` function in your root page that holds your `navigation bar`:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  ContextKeeper().init(context);
}
```

You're now be able to call the `Navigator` based on the saved `context`:

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                ContextKeeper.buildContext, 'screen_without_your_nav_bar', (_) => false);
```

I found that solution in a [comment](https://medium.com/@ekaleonardo/this-is-awesome-article-8d999412fb85) to the article.